# how to push message/notification to every subscriber of One Signal

Tags: android, onesignal

i can push notification to a specific user using its id (notification key)

```
public class SendNotification {

    public SendNotification(String message, String heading, String notificationKey){

        try {
            JSONObject notificationContent = new JSONObject(
                    "{'contents':{'en':'" + message + "'},"+
                    "'include_player_ids':['" + notificationKey + "']," +
                    "'headings':{'en': '" + heading + "'}}");
            OneSignal.postNotification(notificationContent, null);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

as in one signal documentation 
 https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications

there we can push notification to everyone(all the subscribers)

how can i push notification to everyone using code as i can send to a single subscriber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send to all `Active Users` with the `included_segments` key:

**Update:**

It seems like using `include_player_ids` does not require an API Key to send the message. However, using `included_segments`, does - *"Requires your OneSignal App's REST API Key"*

Have ammended the code below to include the `app_id` key.

```
public class SendNotification {

    public SendNotification(String message, String heading, String notificationKey){
            try {
            JSONObject notificationContent = new JSONObject(
                    "{'app_id':\"YOUR_APP_ID\"," +
                    "'contents':{'en':'" + message + "'},"+
                    "'included_segments':[\"Active Users\"]," +
                    "'headings':{'en': '" + heading + "'}}");
            OneSignal.postNotification(notificationContent, null);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-example-code-create-notification

Comment: i tried this one and also used "All" to send notification to all the subscribers but its not working  when i use the above code in my question it is sent and shown in one signal dashboard but using this code to send everyone it don't work

Comment: I've looked again at the link i provided, it seems like using ```include_player_ids``` does not require an API Key to send the message. However, using ```included_segments``` does - _"Requires your OneSignal App's REST API Key"_, under the **Segments** heading

Comment: bro looks like your solution will work  i got this error    can you edit  to place REST API KEY {"errors":["Please include a case-sensitive header of Authorization: Basic \u003cYOUR-REST-API-KEY-HERE\u003e with a valid REST API key."],"reference":["https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/accounts-and-keys#section-keys-ids"]}

Comment: You can see that on the link I added. You might want to use a URI Builder. Enjoy!

Comment: actually there is code in another format  but you converted as in your answer so if you better know please add REST API KEY i copied the same code from  documentation  but it also not working . code is working for playerID  so it will work for segment if you can help with your skills